# Drag and drop between two trees with jqTree

Tags: drag-and-drop, jqtree

By default, as I know, jqTree doesn't support interaction between trees. How can I add drag-and-droppin' ability with a small effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it using the double click event

```
var Tree1 = $('#treeId').tree({
    data: someData,
    dragAndDrop: true,
  }).bind(
      'tree.dblclick',
      function(event) {
          // event.node is the clicked node
          console.log(event.node);
          var selectedNode = Tree2.tree('getSelectedNode');
          console.log(selectedNode);
          Tree2.tree('addNodeAfter',event.node,selectedNode);
      }
  );
```

node will be sent to the other tree on the double click event